# Shorter names to gain access to a class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Just need some advise since I'm new to this. Is there a way I can make this shorter?

```
 Student.Classes.Enum.Enum.gender
```

Just need a smarter way to do this.

Comment: what are you tring to achieve, post some code

Comment: The [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sf0df423.aspx) might help.

Comment: Please describe your problem a little bit more detailed. Are you trying to use that class and do not want to write the whole namesapce along side it?

Comment: I'm not sure why shorter is smarter?

Answer (score 5):

You can use an alias in import like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ShortAlias = Very.Long.Class.Name;

class Test
{
    private ShortAlias x;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you should read up on 'using' statements

i.e.

```
using Student.Classes.Enum.Enum;
```

would allow you to use

```
gender.Male
```